# Is there any method to change the priority of the two assignment methods?

Tags: javascript

This is an interview questions, Asked to write a `Man` class to let the following code can run properly:

```
var me =new  Man();

//method one:
me.attr("fullname", "tom");

//method two:
me.fullname = "jim";

console.info("my name is:" + me.attr("fullname"));

/*------[result is]------
my name is:tom
------------------*/
```

my answer is:

```
var Man=function(){
};

Man.prototype.attr=function(attr,val){
    if(val){
        this[attr]=val;
    }
    else{
        return this[attr];
    }
}
```

The results of my code to run is:

```
/*------[result is]------
my name is:jim
------------------*/
```

who can help me? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a second dictionary:

```
function Man() {
    this.dictionary = {};
}

Man.prototype.attr = function(attr, val) {
    if(arguments.length > 1) {
        this.dictionary[attr] = val;
    } else {
        return this.dictionary[attr];
    }
};
```

You could use a closed variable:

```
function Man() {
    var dictionary = {};

    this.attr = function(attr, val) {
        if(arguments.length > 1) {
            dictionary[attr] = val;
        } else {
            return dictionary[attr];
        }
    };
}
```

You could use a closed `fullname` variable, and ignore everything except `'fullname'`:

```
function Man() {
    var fullname;

    this.attr = function(attr, val) {
        if(attr === 'fullname') {
            if(arguments.length > 1) {
                fullname = val;
            } else {
                return fullname;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

You could also return `"tom"` every single time, or pretend all the attributes are `"fullname"`, or both. You could [ROT13 property names before assigning them](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/KP26g/). You could [add underscores](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/KP26g/1/). You could [create a property instead that throws away values beginning with `"j"`](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/KP26g/2/). The possibilities are limitless, actually.

Answer (score 2):

Use a property to save attributes.

```
var Man=function(){
  this.attributes = {};
};

Man.prototype.attr=function(attr,val){
    if(val){
        this.attributes[attr] = val;
    }
    else{
        return this.attributes[attr];
    }
}
```